# error: cast to 'string' (aka 'char *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: c, string, pointers, cs50

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_valid_key(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || !is_valid_key(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./ceaser key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    string P = get_string("Plaintext:");
    int s = strlen(P);
    int c[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        c[i] = ((int)P[i] + argc) ;
        //printf("argc=%d\n",argc);
        printf("P[%d]=%d\n",i,P[i]);            // for testing purpose
        printf("C[%d]=%s\n\n",i,(string)c[i]);  // for testing purpose`enter code here`
        //printf("\n\n\n");
    }
    printf("C1:%s\n",(string)c);
    return 0;
}

bool is_valid_key(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        char ch = s[i];
        if (!isdigit(ch))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

> error:clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra
> -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    caeser.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o caeser caeser.c:52:33: error: cast to
> 'string' (aka 'char *') from smaller integer type 'int'
> [-Werror,-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> printf("C[%d]=%s\n\n",i,(string)c[i]);

I think you might be aware of the caeser topic from the cs50 course, so I was working on this code and I got this error, I really don't know how to solve it, if u know then please let me know, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste of the error. Also please include a comment in the code where you get it.

Comment: And the error message would be referring to which line?

Comment: `c[i]` is a `int` type. Casting it is unlikely to convert it to a meaningful pointer to an array of `char` expected by `%s`.

Comment: you want `%d` instead of `%s`

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are faulty:

```
printf("P[%d]=%d\n",i,P[i]);            // for testing purpose
printf("C[%d]=%s\n\n",i,(string)c[i]);  // for testing purpose`enter code here`
```

In the first you print a `char` using the `%d` format, which prints it as an `int`.

Then in the second line you attempt to print an `int` value using the `%s` format, which is for strings.

To solve your problem, change to the correct `printf` formnat specifier and don't to the casting:

```
// Note different format here
//             v
printf("P[%d]=%c\n",i,P[i]);            // for testing purpose
printf("C[%d]=%d\n\n",i,c[i]);  // for testing purpose`enter code here`
//             ^
// Note different format here, as well as no casting needed
```

Comment: I think there's another print statement that needs fixed: `printf("C1:%s\n",(string)c);`

Comment: so is there any other way to solve my issue bcoz if won't do casting then I won't be able to get the exact output

Comment: @ChristianGibbons what modifications should I do?

Comment: @Sushmitashukla What are you trying to accomplish? What is the output you want?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude visit this link:  https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/caesar/,  you will get to know what output do I want....

Comment: @Sushmitashukla For some specific input and command-line arguments, what *exactly* do you expect `printf("C1:%s\n",(string)c);` to print? What should the contents of `c` be? And why do you think you can just convert an array of integers into a string? Perhaps you should stop using CS50 and instead get a few books to learn properly instead (especially about the differences between strings and arrays, what really makes a string a string, and how to print (non-string) arrays)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, thank you for helping.